# Get arguments from a view

Tags: views

I have a view object and I'd like to get the contextual filters that were passed to it.

I have this tidbit of code that prints out the arguments field name.

```
if (!empty($view->argument)) {
  foreach ($view->argument as $id => $arg) {
    print $arg->field;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the values of those fields.

Answer (score 10):

`$view->args[0]` returns the first argument.

Answer (score 5):

A dynamic solution:

```
foreach ($view->argument as $id => $arg) {
  $pos = $arg->position;
  print $view->args[$pos];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 I've used such variant based on the answers above.

```
foreach ($view->argument as $arg) {
    if ($arg->getPluginId() != 'node_nid') {
      continue;
    }
    $node = Node::load($arg->getValue());
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use:

```
$info = $view->get_items($type);
```

Where $type is some type from here:
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/views_object_types/7

Probably for your case could be:

```
$contextual_filters = $view->get_items('argument');
```

Ahother option could be to target a specific contextual filter for performing some alterations (i.e. hook_views_whatever):
In that case you could probably use:

```
$my_filter = $view->get_item($display_id, $type, $id);
```

Perform whatever you want to do with that filter, and then:

```
$view->set_item($display_id, $type, $id, $my_filter);
```

Comment: Kindly test your solution before posting here. "Maybe", "probably" isnt something the people want to see here. :)

Comment: Hi Pratip Ghosh, "Maybe" refers to one choice you could use and "probably" means here that is the best solution that I can think whitout knowing where that code is being called. That $view object could come from many hooks, handlers...